# Why do all PHP parse errors start with "T_"?

Tags: php, parse-error

I just want to know is whether there is any reason/story behind to use `T_` before parse errors like

```
parse error : unexpected `T_`ELSE in ... blah blah blah  
parse error : Unexpected `T_`IF in ....blah   
parse error : unexpected `T_`VAR  
parse error : unexpected `T_`STRING
```

and many more.

Can you provide any link for clarification? Also, are there any other prefixes used in error displaying then please share.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`T` stands for [**T**oken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_%28parser%29#Token).

These errors are telling you that the parser found a *token* that it didn't expect.

Answer (score 5):

Because those are, from the point of view of a parser, `tokens`, thus the `T_` (that's the same reasoning why error levels start with `E_` ...).

Answer (score 3):

T from `token`.
It's because of [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) part of PHP execution process

Answer (score 1):

ELSE, IF, VAR, STRING, FUNCTION, etc. would be individual tokens that are important to the parser.  I assume that the T_ prefix is just a style to indicate that those things are tokens.